# React subaccordions are not full width

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

This should be an easier question, but I can't find the answer for it. I have a simple React form, and I want to put multiple levels accordions. I manage to create the subaccordions, but those are not full width. The react application is available at https://iquasere.github.io/MOSGUITO/ , with the broken accordions at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sub-accordians are displaying as expected because of the `flex` property, the default flex direction is `row`. Just update the direction of the container and it should work.

```css
.MuiAccordionDetails-root {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; // <-- Here
    padding: 8px 16px 16px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it!